# Как правильно организовать связь ManyToMany между одним и тем же entity в Spring Boot

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, many-to-many

У меня появилась необходимость удалять User'a, но из-за того, что у него есть связи(подписки и подписчики), объект не удаляется, как мне правильно это реализовать?

Exception, который возникает:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sweater_db`.`sweater_user_subscribers`, CONSTRAINT `user_role_subscribers_subscriber_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`subscriber_id`) REFERENCES `sweater_user` (`id`))
```

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sweater_user")
public class User implements UserDetails{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Username should not be empty")
    private String username;

    @NotBlank(message = "Password should not be empty")
    private String password;

    @Email(message = "Email is not correct")
    @NotBlank(message = "Email should not be empty")
    private String email;

    private String activationCode;

    private boolean active;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "sweater_user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Collection<Role> roles;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<Message> messages;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "sweater_user_subscribers",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "channel_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subscriber_id")
    )
    private Set<User> subscribers = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "sweater_user_subscriptions",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "subscriber_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "channel_id")
    )
    private Set<User> subscriptions = new HashSet<>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно ругается.
У Вас остаются внешние ключи, которые не дают удалить запись в БД.

Если решать прямо в лоб в Вашем конкретно случае, то можно было бы воспользоваться обратными вызовами жизненного цикла сущности.
В частности можно воспользоваться событием `preRemove`, которое генерируется перед удалением экземпляра сущности.

Вы можете подписаться на данное событие проставив аннотацию `@PreRemove` перед методом модели User, который будет обрабатывать данное событие.

Там Вы можете "обнулить" связи с данным пользователем.

```
    @PreRemove
    private void preRemove() {
        // проходимся по всем подписчикам и удаляем у них из подписок нас любимых
        for (User user : subscribers) {
            user.getSubscriptions().remove(this);
        }
        // проходимся по всем подпискам и удаляем их
        for (User user : subscriptions) {
            this.getSubscriptions().remove(user);
        }
    }
```

**Замечание**

Хочу обратить Ваше внимание на то, что Вы используете две разных таблицы (одну для подписок, другую для подписчиков).

Я сомневаюсь, что это то, чего Вы хотели.
Что то мне подсказывает, что таблица должна быть одна и та же, просто ключи должны разные использоваться.

**Предложение**

На Вашем месте для подписки я бы вообще использовал отдельную сущность `Subscription` с полями:

- `User channel;`
- `User subscriber;`

В таком случае в User на соответствующих связях Вы бы могли просто проставить `CASCADE_DELETE` и все.